# How do I rename a Firefox Add-On to a readable name?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I created a firefox Addon with the Addon-SDK and now the name of this addon in my `~/.mozilla/firefox/{profilenr}.default/extensions` folder is just

```
jid1-87IRl0MTVi6VpQ@jetpack.xpi
```

How can I set this name?

Comment: That's just how the addon sdk packs it. You can rename the xpi file before installing it. it might be related to the id of the addon, so in install.rdf change the id if renaming the xpi pre install doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify an `id` in [`package.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json) instead of the auto-generated one.

```
{
  "id": "myaddon@example.org"
}
```

This `id` must be [a valid add-on id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#id).

Also, renaming the ids of already published add-ons is problematic. While the `AddonManager` supports this, e.g. the [Mozilla Add-ons site](https://addons.mozilla.org/) cannot change ids once your add-on was registered with it.